# How to add a TFS 2015 GIT Based Build on an existing Windows Based Jenkins Server

Tags: git, jenkins, tfs, azure-devops

I have read through the existing questions regarding Jenkins and GIT and TFS integration.

I have an existing server (2008R2) where I have fun Subversion based builds, now our development team is using TFS Visual Studio Online with GIT as the Source and I have no idea how to go about setting up a New build to do this...
They eventually want me to publish the build to a test server for testing to access.  This is all very new to me. So far at this point i have been used to just making MSI and .exe.  Can anyone show me a Blog, Video or document on how this can be done?

One other note this server is using Apache-Tomcat 7.0 to host the Jenkins installation on the 2008 R2 server.
thank you in advance.

Comment: TFS GIT is just GIT - you should be able to setup jenkins with a git source same as any other GIT provider.

Comment: I am getting this error right now with how I have it seup:
Repository URL Failed to connect to repository : Command "C:\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h https://XXXXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/XXXXX HEAD" returned status code 128: stdout: stderr: fatal: unable to access

Comment: Have you [enabled alternate credentials](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/auth/overview)?

Comment: yes, and that is the user I setup to do the git repository.

Comment: Consider using the build automation in VSO instead of a separate tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you have found a solution for this as it has been some time. If not, I discovered that my Jenkins server would only authenticate to my TFS 2015 based git repos if the TFS IIS instance had basic authentication

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding additional information, like reference links how to change the relevant settings.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario: source code is stored in Visual Studio Online and continue to use Jenkins for continuous integration builds, please check this msdn article for the details how to get it work: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/integrate/service-hooks/jenkins-and-vso-vs

Comment: I am actually trying to just run a daily Official Build for our product on a server we manage. We use VSO for the CI builds but we would like to have a Local build of the product to push to test servers...